# How to enable SIGQUIT core dumps with apport?

Tags: debugging, apport, ulimit

I noticed that on a 12.04 system setting `ulimit -c unlimited` and sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> does not have the expected result.

Though the shell prints

```
^\zsh: quit (core dumped)
```

no core dump is written as far as I can tell.

The file `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` contains an `apport` pipe - thus, it seems that by default `apport` is now responsible for writing core dumps.

The directory `/var/crash` does not contain a recent core dump for my application.

Thus my question: Is apport ignoring SIGQUIT induced core dumps?

If yes:

- Shouldn't that be considered a bug?
- How can I configure apport such that it does not ignore SIGQUIT?

(As a workaround setting `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to `core` works as expected, i.e. I get a core dump named `core` into my CWD after hitting SIGQUIT.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, apport is ignoring SIGQUIT and yes, it's a bug IMO.

I reported it in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1153662 with a patch, and a fix has been released.

Answer (score 2):

Apport filters coredumps on SIGQUIT. You'll find a discussion on Launchpad about that issue ([dumps core on SIGQUIT](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/62511)). There are good arguments to change this behaviour, but is not clear if Ubuntu will do it.